# Telerik RadTextBox with exclamation mark

Tags: telerik

The RadTextBox in this example shows an exclamation mark icon (!) if no input is available. The example on this page shows how to use RadInputManager to extend normal asp textboxes to have the exclamation mark:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/input/examples/radinputmanager/firstlook/defaultcs.aspx

However, there doesn't seem to be an example as to how this exclamation mark can be displayed if I am already using a RadTextBox... Is this feasible?

---

It's worth noting that I am interested in this because it's cleaner than writing out an error message... Any other technique (ie highlighting the empty text box etc.) would work equally well for me.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you can do the same by attaching asp RequiredFieldValidator to your RadTextBox and display the icon as part of your validator error message. Still the more convenient way is to use asp TextBoxes and RadInputManager, especially when you have several textboxes in place.

Dick

Answer (score 2):

RadTextBox does not support the RadInputManager validations.  You have to apply those validations against the standard asp Textboxes.

Having said that, you can use the RegExpTextBoxSetting and TextBoxSettings from within the RadInputManager to get the same results (or close to) that you would have from the RadTextBox control.

However, in essence, you can either use the RadInputManager with standard ASP Textboxes or you can use the RadTextBox controls, not both.

Took me a while to figure that one out...

Answer (score 0):

I found just using the RadTextBox straight out was easier than dealing with ASP Textboxes combined with RadInputManager.  To me, it's like doing the work twice when you use the comboed approach vs how the RadTextBox deals with themselves.  Of course, you will always have trade-offs I'm sure but I can't recall any that really mattered at the time.